# Transform a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

This loop

```
$demo = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($big_array);$i++){
    echo 'Page['.$i.'][0]: '.$big_array[$i][0].'<br>';
    for($j=1;$j<count($big_array[$i]);$j++){

        echo 'Email['.$i.']['.$j.']: '.$big_array[$i][$j].'<br>';
        $demo[$big_array[$i][$j]][] = $big_array[$i][$j-1]; //something is not ok with this
    }
}
```

gives me this:

```
Page[0][0]: http://www.example.com/impressum
Email[0][1]: sales@example.com
Email[0][2]: support@example.com
Page[1][0]: http://www.example.com/termsofuse
Email[1][1]: support@example.com
Email[1][2]: terms1@example.com
Email[1][3]: terms2@example.com
Email[1][4]: ad2@example.com
Page[2][0]: http://www.example.com/adpolicy
Email[2][1]: support@example.com
Email[2][2]: ad1@example.com
Email[2][3]: ad2@example.com
Email[2][4]: ad1@example.com
```

How can I transform it to get this result:

```
sales@example.com
  http://www.example.com/impressum
support@example.com
  http://www.example.com/impressum
  http://www.example.com/termsofuse
  http://www.example.com/adpolicy
terms1@example.com
  http://www.example.com/termsofuse
terms2@example.com
  http://www.example.com/termsofuse
ad2@example.com
  http://www.example.com/termsofuse
  http://www.example.com/adpolicy
ad1@example.com
  http://www.example.com/adpolicy
```

var_dump($big_array):

```
array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'http://www.example.com/impressum', 1 => 'sales@example.com', 2 => 'support@example.com', ), 1 => array ( 0 => 'http://www.example.com/termsofuse', 1 => 'support@example.com', 2 => 'terms1@example.com', 3 => 'terms2@example.com', 4 => 'ad2@example.com', ), 2 => array ( 0 => 'http://www.example.com/adpolicy', 1 => 'support@example.com', 2 => 'ad1@example.com', 3 => 'ad2@example.com', 4 => 'ad1@example.com', ), )
```

Comment: Can you `var_export()` the original array please?

Comment: Sure, take a look at it

Comment: the relationship between input and output is not clear

Comment: The input array lists Email addresses per URL - the required output lists URLs per Email.  Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'http://www.example.com/impressum', 1 => 'sales@example.com', 2 => 'support@example.com', ), 1 => array ( 0 => 'http://www.example.com/termsofuse', 1 => 'support@example.com', 2 => 'terms1@example.com', 3 => 'terms2@example.com', 4 => 'ad2@example.com', ), 2 => array ( 0 => 'http://www.example.com/adpolicy', 1 => 'support@example.com', 2 => 'ad1@example.com', 3 => 'ad2@example.com', 4 => 'ad1@example.com', ), );

print_r($array);

$final = array();
foreach ( $array as $group )
{
    for ( $i=1; $i<count($group); $i++ )
    {
        $final[$group[$i]][] = $group[0];
    }
}

print_r($final);
```

[Here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#RioAdkZTz) is the PHP Playground result.

To format it like your example:

```
foreach ( $final as $email => $links )
{
    echo $email . "\n";
    foreach ( $links as $link )
    {
        echo "  " . $link . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! I managed to get the same result by fixing my line as `$demo[$big_array[$i][$j]][] = $big_array[$i][0];`. Any ideas on how to print out the result in a way I showed in my question?

Comment: Like echo it out with spaces in your question? It looks like you have some random spaces in your answer. Format it exactly like you want it to be shown.

Comment: But the last two links in your example only have one space before it. (I'm pretty sure this isn't intended.) I updated my answer with how to format it.